# Index rebuild canceled because of .mdf growth

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have the Standard Edition of SQL Server 2012 and used a script to rebuild index. I ran the query and then I saw that the `.mdf` file for the database started the grow a lot.

I chose to cancel/stop my query that run the rebuild of the database.

I checked in database what happened with the following queries:

```
SP_who2 

select cmd,* 
from sys.sysprocesses 
where blocked > 0
```

I saw that a process where blocked so I chose to kill that one.

The query/spid became marked with cancel/rollback in `SP_who2`.

It took a lot of time to rollback the query.

The table that was rebuilding was a big with over 4 million rows and a fragmentation of 99%.

My questions are:

1. Why did the `.mdf` grow that fast? About 1 gb/(10/sec)
2. When I stopped my query, can the database get inconsistent in any way?
3. Can the data in the database have been changed because of this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is bit incomplete as you have not posted the query used to rebuild the index. A lot depends on what options you selected during index rebuild. Did you use the GUI with default options? The size of the mdf file would also be affected by the Fill Factor value chosen during index rebuild.

> 1.Why did the .mdf grow that fast? About 1 gb/(10/sec)

Gerenal answer would be "YES", MDF file does grow during index rebuild because an index rebuild requires creating a new index first, and that would be created on the same drive where the data file resides, unless you have used `SORT_IN_TEMPDB` option, which would force intermediate sorts to be done in `tempdb` instead. Only after the new index is created will the old one be dropped so you can now see why space grew. Also, the space created by dropping the old index would not be released immediately. To release space you would need to run `dbcc shrinkfile`, although it is not advised.

If space is an issue on the drive where the data file resides you can use `sort_in_tempdb` option while rebuilding indexes. Please note that the intermediate sort results that are used to build the index are stored in `tempdb`. If `tempdb` is on a different set of disks to the user database, this may reduce the time needed to create an index. However, this increases the total amount of disk space that is used during the index build.

> 2.When I stopped my query, can the database get inconsistent in any way?

No, the database won't be in an inconsistent state. Rebuild is considered a single transaction by SQL Server so either it completes fully or things are returned to what they were before the index rebuild.

> 3.Can the data in the database have been changed because of this?

No, rest assured data cannot change.

I strongly suggest you to read the Blog [Why data file increased after index rebuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlprogrammability/why-did-the-size-of-my-indexes-expand-when-i-rebuilt-my-indexes)
Please also read [Misconceptions Around Index rebuild by Paul Randal](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/search-engine-qa-19-misconceptions-around-index-rebuilds-allocation-bulk_logged-mode-locking/)

My other question would be did you try [Ola Hallengren solution for index rebuild](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) and stats updating? It's a good one and uses an intelligent script.

Comment: Thank's a lot!!! I actually used Ola:s script but when the index rebuild for one index growth the datafile that much I thought it was anything wrong.               What is the recommendation to release space after rebuild in data file?

Comment: You would have to run dbcc shrinkfile to recover space, but please dont run it SQL Server will utilize that space. If Ola script is in place and  still you find space issue you might as well have to add more disk space or use tempdb as pointed in answer

Comment: Is there any other reason to choose sort in tempdb than if i have to little space on data file disk?

Comment: You must read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188281.aspx